# Dual fixed point

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> Let $E$ be a Banach space, let $T:E\to E$ have norm $1$ and let $\nu\in E^*\setminus\{0\}$ be such that $T^*\nu=\nu$. Under which conditions there is $e\in E$ such that $Te=e$ and $\langle e,\nu\rangle\ne 0$?

This is true for reflexive spaces. Indeed, WLOG $\|\nu\|=1$. Consider $D=\nu^{-1}(1)\cap \overline{B}_{E}$, which is weakly compact and non-empty. Then $T_{D}$ is weak-to-weak continuous self-map of $D$. Therefore, there is a fixed point due to Tychonoff fixed point theorem. **Thus, I am looking for conditions significantly weaker than reflexivity.**

REMARK: In fact, the argument works if there is a linear topology on $E$ such that $T$ and $\nu$ are continuous with respect to that topology and $\overline{B}_{E}$ is compact in that topology.

Comment: The existence of such an $e$ for each $\nu$ is equivalent to $T$ being mean ergodic.

Comment: @JochenGlueck do you mean for every $\nu$ that is a fixed point of $T^*$? If so, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I mean for every $\nu$ that is a fixed point of $T^*$. I added an answer with details and a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1 of the answer.** In terms of $T$, the property you are looking for is characterized by the *mean ergodic theorem*:

**Theorem.** Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on $E$ that is *power-bounded* in the sense that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}\|T^n\| < \infty$. Then the following assertions are equivalent:

(i) $T$ is *mean ergodic*, i.e. the sequence of *Cesàro means* $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges strongly.

(ii) The fixed space of the dual operator $T^*$ is separated by the fixed space of the operator $T$, i.e. for every $0 \not= \nu \in \ker(1 - T^*)$ there exists $0 \not= e \in \ker(1-T)$ such that $\langle \nu, e \rangle \not= 0$.

(iii) The space $E$ is the topologically direct sum of the fixed space $\ker(1-T)$ and the closure of the range of $1-T$.

This is a classical theorem in operator theory. You can find it, for instance, in Theorem 8.20 of [T. Eisner, B. Farkas, M. Haase, R. Nagel: *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory* (2015)] (actually, the theorem there contains several more equivalent assertions and is not only stated for power-bounded operators but for the slightly larger class of *Cesàro bounded* operators).

The result for reflexive spaces that is stated in the question is a special case of the above theorem since every power-bounded operator on a reflexive Banach space is mean ergodic [op. cit., Theorem 8.22].

**Part 2 of the answer.** The question on which spaces every power-bounded (or contractive) operator is mean-ergodic is a very subtle one.

- In the paper [V. P. Fonf, M. Lin, P. Wojtaszczyk: Ergodic Characterizations of Reflexivity of Banach Spaces (Journal of Functional Analysis, 2001)] it is shown that a Banach space with a Schauder basis is necessarily reflexive if every power-bounded operator on it is mean ergodic.
- In the paper [V. P. Fonf, M. Lin, P. Wojtaszczyk: A non-reflexive Banach space with all contractions mean ergodic (Israel Journal of Mathematics, 2010)] it is shown that there exist non-reflexive Banach spaces an which every operator $T$ of norm $\|T\| \le 1$ is mean ergodic.

Comment: We may add that the limit in (i) is the linear projector onto $\ker(I-T)$ associated with the decomposition in (iii)

Comment: Thank you! A small correction: in (ii) the latter is separated by the former.

Comment: This is however, not exactly what I was looking for; I was more interested in conditions on $E$ and $\nu$...

Comment: @erz: Thank you for the correction; I corrected (ii) accordingly. Concerning your second comment, I added a second part to the answer: for most Banach spaces, one cannot weaken the reflexivity assumption if one wants all power-bounded operators to be mean ergodic.

Comment: The thing is, I don't need this property to hold for every $\nu$, I need it to hold for a **given** $\nu$, and so it may depend on $\nu$. This should be a geometric condition that takes into account the way the kernel of $\nu$ dissects the unit ball of $E$. Thank you nonetheless!